# how to take sum and display it in vuetify datatable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Hi friends I am new to Vue. Pleas help me I am using vue2, vuetify 0.17 and datatable component. My problem is I want to take sum of area, floor columns from the data. I calculated the running total using map function and stored it in total{'area' : 100, 'floor':7}. Now in footer  I want to display the totals.

```
<v-data-table
v-bind:headers="listData.columnProperty"
v-bind:items="listData.data"
v-bind:search="search"
:totals="{area : 100, flat : 7}" //is it allowed
>
<template slot="footer" slot-scope="totals">
Footer {{ totals}} {{ totals['area']}}
</template>
```

Please share any example which create a total and displays it into the footer. I need it badly.

Comment: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/2474 In such case how do we display the totals in the footer ? There should be some way

Comment: Use the `body.append` slot instead as show here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60951401/vuetify-align-footer-columns-with-table-columns-in-data-table

Answer (score 1):

You said you have it calculated in `totals`, so would this work?

```
<template slot="footer">
    <td><strong>Sum</strong></td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ totals.area }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ totals.flat }}</td> 
</template>
```

(not sure how rest of your table looks, but maybe you get the idea)