# Vuetify Align footer columns with table columns in data table

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js, footer

I have a datatable (vuetify 2.1.12) with slot="items" and slot="footer".
In the footer I wan't to display the sum of some of the columns.
The "problem" is that the columns in the footer are not at all in line with the columns in the table.

basically I do this in the data table:

```
             <template v-slot:item="props">
                <tr>
                  <td>{{ props.item.qty }}</td>
                  <td>{{ props.item.qtyBoughtToday }}</td>
                  <td>{{ props.item.shortName }}</td>
                </tr>
              </template>
              <template slot="footer">
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>{{ sumQtyBoughtToday }}</td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
             </template>
```

The thing is that the footer column "sumQtyBoughtToday" does not end up in the same place at all as the column props.item.qtyBoughtToday.

So...how to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `body.append` slot instead of the `footer`...

```
 <template slot="body.append">
      <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>{{ sumQtyBoughtToday }}</td>
          <td></td>
      </tr>
 </template>
```

Example: https://codeply.com/p/kIlxX2jTZ1

Comment: Yes thank you sir, that was what I was looking for!